# Unable to install packages using apt-get (Strange error)

Tags: apt

```
    prathya@Shriyansh:~$ sudo apt-get install  i8kutils
    [sudo] password for prathya: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    i8kutils is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Setting up android-studio (4.5-0ubuntu0) ...
    unzip:  cannot find or open /opt/android-studio-ide-*, /opt/android-studio-ide-*.zip or /opt/android-studio-ide-*.ZIP.
    No zipfiles found.
    rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/android-studio-ide-*’: No such file or directory
    find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
    find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
    dpkg: error processing package android-studio (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    android-studio
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what Android Studio has to do with it..

Comment: Seems the `post-installation` script is having some problems for the package `andrino-studio`. Do you have the `zipfile` by any of the names given? Also try to create a directory named `/opt/android-studio` and then try again..BTW `i8kutils is already the newest version.`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the package and starting the process over again.

First purge the package:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge android-studio
```